# Where is this user-agent from? "MozacFetch"

Tags: user-agent

In cloudflare, I have a firewall rule to only allow certain user-agents. This one is always getting blocked because I haven't allowed it but I am wondering if it should be allowed? Not sure if it's coming from a legit browser or some automated program?

Anyone know where it comes from?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the nightly version of Firefox's new-generation browser on Android, Fenix:

https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/fenix

Comment: Interesting... Thank you